# Is it possible to initialize a vector with different instances of a class passing different parameters to constructor?

Tags: c++

I want to initialize the vector students with different instances of class Student. So, if I want to define a vector with 3 students, I can do it like in the code example but then I have the problem that all students have the same id "a". Is it possible to initialize the different students with different ids, so that the first student has the id "a", the second has the id "b" and the third has the id "c", like in the vector ids? Or even better, is it possible to initialize each student with a different element of vector ids without using a setter-method?
Thank you in advance.

```cpp
//Student.h

#ifndef STUDENT_H_
#define STUDENT_H_

#include <string>
using namespace std;

class Student {
private:
    string id;
public:
    Student(string id) {
        this->id = id;
    };
    virtual ~Student() {

    }
};

#endif /* STUDENT_H_ */
```

```cpp
//Test.cpp

#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include "Student.h"
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> ids {"a", "b", "c"};
    vector<Student> students(3, Student("a"));
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use @vlad's answer, alternatively you can do

```
std::vector<Student> students{ std::string( "a" ), std::string( "b" ), std::string( "c" ) };
```

or, adding a new constructor to your class

```
    Student(const char* id): id{id} {};
```

you can do something like

```
vector<Student> students2{"a", "b",  "c"};
```

Lastly regarding the last question

> is it possible to initialize each student with a different element of vector ids without using a setter-method?

you can do (if I understand it correctly)

```
std::vector<std::string> ids{"d", "e", "f"};
vector<Student> students3;
std::transform(cbegin(ids), cend(ids), std::back_inserter(students3), [](const std::string& id){return Student{id};});
```

Play around with my code at: https://onlinegdb.com/SysWTjXyB

Answer (score 3):

Do you mean the following?

```
std::vector<Student> students = { Student( "a" ), Student( "b" ), Student( "c" ) };
```

Answer (score 1):

> Or even better, is it possible to initialize each student with a different element of vector `ids` without using a setter-method?

Use `std::transform`:

```
std::vector<std::string> ids {"a", "b", "c"};
std::vector<Student> students;

students.reserve(ids.size());
std::transform(ids.begin(), ids.end(), std::back_inserter(students),
    [](auto& /* const std::string& */ id) {
        return Student(id);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Using [`std::for_each`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/for_each) you can [`emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) Students one by one in their vector.

```
std::vector<std::string> ids {"a", "b", "c"};
std::vector<Student> students;

std::for_each(ids.cbegin(), ids.cend(),
                  [&students](auto id){students.emplace_back(id);});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a static member which will be incremented into the constructor. Something like that:

```
class Student {
...
public:
    char GetId() const;
...
private:
    static char id = 'a';
}
```

Don't forget to check boundary conditions before incrementing the id var. ('a' - 'z')

Answer (score 0):

I have made few small changes in `Student` class and those are, initialing `id` by `member initializer` and added a function named `value()` to print value. Another change is, i have removed `using namespace std;` because it is considered bad practice. See below code,

```
#include <iostream>

#include <string>
#include <vector>

class Student {
private:
    std::string id;
public:
    Student( const std::string& id): id( id)
    {
    }

    virtual ~Student()
    {

    }

    const std::string& value() const noexcept
    {
        return id;
    }
};

int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> ids { "a", "b", "c"};
    std::vector<Student> students( ids.begin(), ids.end());

    std::vector<Student>::iterator it = students.begin();

    while( students.end() != it)
    {
        std::cout<< it->value()<< ", ";
        ++it;
    }

    std::cout<< std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

`std::vector` class have a constructor

```
template< class InputIt >
vector( InputIt first, InputIt last, 
        const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

It construct `std::vector` with the contents of the range `[first, last)`, here `first` and `last` must satisfies `LegacyInputIterator`.
Now import point is how this statement is working,
`std::vector<Student> students( ids.begin(), ids.end());` because `*first` (iterator of `std::vector< std::string>`) would give a `std::string` value but `students` is `std::vector<Student>` type and need `Student` objects to initialize.
It became possible because `Student` class construct is not a `explicit` constructor and due to this `std::string` implicitly convertible to `Student`.

output: `a, b, c,`